# Sprockets Rails Helper Asset Not Precompiled even though declared in config/initializers/assets.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, precompile

I have a rails API with a mailer. In my mailer layout, I include an image :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <%= image_tag "quickbed_logo" %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

that is stored in app/assets/images.

However when I m sending the email I get :

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled - Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( quickbed_logo )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server:
```

I complied with the error message and added  `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( quickbed_logo )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

However I still get the error. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried adding the extension to your filename? Rails cannot really guess it. Also, when you run 'RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile` is the image precompiled?

Comment: have you restarted you server?

Comment: @PoloniculMov adding the extension solved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the extension to `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( quickbed_logo.png )` because Rails cannot guess it.

Comment: What is the full file path of `config/initializers/assets.rb`? What's the parent directory at least? Why is this even necessary? Why doesn't it work via `applications.js`?

Comment: @iyrin the parent directory is the application's folder.